# how start one animation after the second is finished?

Tags: jquery, css-animations

How to start one animation after the second is finished.

```
$('#about').addClass('animated fadeOutUp');
$('#contact').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
```

I use http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ for animation

Comment: Here they use transition delays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery chaining for this... Or add a callback function...

$('selector').addClass('class').animate({animationhere});
Or

$('selector').addClass('class1',function(){
Do other here
});

Comment: Just show him how a callback would work and I think you'll have an acceptable answer.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know the difference on comment and answer here just trying to help